# How to clear WPF ItemList after binding the itemsource?

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a list:

```
private ObservableCollection<SensorListViewItemModel> sensorList = new ObservableCollection<SensorListViewItemModel>();
```

In which my Model is this:

```
    public class SensorListViewItemModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the internal Id.
    /// </summary>
    public Guid InternalId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or sets the point.
    /// </summary>
    public System.Drawing.PointF PointOnImage { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the number of this sensor.
    /// </summary>
    public int Number { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the fill color.
    /// </summary>
    public Color Color { get; set; } = Colors.Black;

    /// <summary>
    /// Covnerter for Brush and MVVM Data Binding in the ListView
    /// </summary>
    public Brush ColorAsBrush
    {
        get
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Color);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I bind this in my WindowLoaded Event of my WPF window to my ListView:

```
        this.SensorListView.ItemsSource = this.sensorList;
```

Now I add some items which works fine:

```
  this.sensorList = new ObservableCollection<SensorListViewItemModel>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            this.sensorList.Add(new SensorListViewItemModel()
            {
                Number = i,
                Name = "Sensor " + i,
                Color = ColorHelper.FromStringAsMediaColor(this.userSettings.DataSerieColors[i - 1])
            });
        }
```

Now the item list shows 5 items - okay.

Now I want to clear the iteams:

```
                    this.sensorList.Clear();
```

or

```
            this.sensorList = new ObservableCollection<SensorListViewItemModel>();
```

but both doesn't work

Comment: Please explain what exactly "*doesn't work*" means. As a note `this.SensorListView.ItemsSource = this.sensorList;` is not a binding, just an ordinary assignment.

Comment: As another note, `sensorList` should be readonly, and you should always just call `Clear` instead of assigning a new collection instance.

Comment: Well, it is a binding, right? Because it is a Observable collection, all edit and add data will changing the listview?! (at least edit and add works)

With "doesnt work" I mean, the items I added before are still within the least view, even when the Observable collection is cleared

Comment: No, it's not a Binding. A Binding would be declared in XAML like `ItemsSource="{Binding ...}"` or in code behind like `SensorListView.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { ... });`

Comment: Anyway, `sensorList.Clear();` should clear the ItemsControl, provided it's the same collection that was assigned in `SensorListView.ItemsSource = sensorList;`

Comment: Well, even if it should, it doesnt work.

Comment: As said, make it readonly - `private readonly ObservableCollection<SensorListViewItemModel> sensorList = ...` - to make sure not to deal with multiple instances.

Comment: Okay, I dont know why this changed anything here, but it works after setting it to readonly. Thank you.

Comment: Again as said, it "*makes sure not to deal with multiple instances*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole purpose of `ObservableCollection` is that you should only create it once, and then just modify the existing collection.

As Clemens has pointed out in the comments, you're not doing data-binding - you need a public property on your ViewModel for that.

So your ViewModel code should be something like

```
public class SensorListViewModel
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<SensorListViewItemModel> _sensorList = new ObservableCollection<SensorListViewItemModel>(); 

    public IEnumerable<SensorListViewItemModel> SensorList => _sensorList;

    private void AddSensorItems(IEnumerable<SensorListViewItemModel> items, bool clearExistingItems)
    {
        if (clearExistingItems)
            _sensorList.Clear();

        foreach(var item in items)
            _sensorList.Add(item);
    }
```

Note that you don't have to declare the SensorList property as `ObservableCollection` - the binding will take care of that.

Then in your View, set its `DataContext` to an instance of SensorListViewModel and bind the ItemsSource property of the ListView to the SensorList property.